# How to add customized right click menu like dropbox does on macintosh (cocoa or any programming language)

Tags: macos, menu, contextmenu

Is there any way to add customized right click menu like dropbox does. I did check services in Automator but did not find it useful (actually i am not sure how to use automator only for a group of files within a folder).

Does anyone has customize the right click menu in Macintosh?